# In an Approval Process select Approver to be a Queue

Tags: approval-process, queue

I am in the process of creating Parallel Approval process.

**Use Case:**  An Opportunity should be unanimously approved by three teams.

**What i have tried. ?**

Opprtunity is not supported in Queues, so created a new custom object, which would be submitted for approval. This custom object is a child of Opprtunity in a M-D relationship. The idea behind this is that the child object can be surfaced on the lightning record page of the Parent (Opportunity)

Unfortunately Child in a M-D  relationship is not supported in Queues.

Has anyone tried a workaround? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

What I can think of is:

1. use a lookup relationship instead of MD (you might need some other workarounds to e.g. prevent orphan approval records and to have rollups to Opportunity)
2. use an alternative approvals package. E.g. [Approvals Pro](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FMcp7UAD) supports parallel approvals on any object (full disclosure: I'm affiliated with Approvals Pro).